# does the service's path in init.rc needed in /system/bin

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk

From the generic init.c,I can see that all the service's path is under /system/bin.
And,I build my native code and put it under the /data.Also,I register it in the init.rc as a service.
But,it fails to auto-run when the android start up.
So,i wonder whether the service is needed to put under /system/bin?
And,what's more,as we do not have the permission to make a file under the /system/bin,do we need to  re-build the whole os from the source to build my code in the /system/bin?Or,there is another way to accomplish my goal?
I have suffered for such problems several days.

Comment: The reason it fails to auto-run is the permissions is not set, even the same for user and group ownership. Is the handset rooted?

Comment: not yet.And,would u mind to clarify ur idea?Thank u in advance!